# Xcode 8 with legacy Swift 2.3: SourceKit imposes Swift 3.0 rules & shows phantom errors

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8, swift2, sourcekit

It seems Xcode is passive-aggressively encouraging me to switch to Swift 3.0. As I type code, and when I invoke a build, all kinds of warnings & errors relating to Swift 3.0 syntax show up, only to disappear once compilation finishes.

It seems the dynamic incremental compilation setting on the "left hand" is not talking to the static actual compilation setting on the "right hand".

It's very distracting. This is Xcode GM 8.1. Has anyone else experienced this and found a workaround?

Comment: Sounds like you should write a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

It's testing your <strike>inner strength</strike> 2.3 vs 3.0 knowledge.
You have to stay firm and shtick to the syntax of the days of the yore.
Consider that one of life's challenges. Do not give in to the 3.0 provocations.
Cause if you show weakness for one single moment and give in there will be changes to undo to get it to compile with 2.3.

Stay strong. There is more yet to come. I think 8.2 beta will be dumped onto out unsuspecting heads shortly. *[Ed: Indeed, already: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html*]

Comment: I will upvote for humor but not accept it as the answer :-)

Comment: Thanks. To be fair to flying saucer employees, noone told them: you can scrap the eclipse extension and rewrite into an android studio that's finally useable(?). There is no iSteve to approve a radical move into: Xcode. The Spartan Edition.